# Who vs that differences

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> 1. I don’t know any man **that** is present here.
> 2. I don’t know any man **who** is present here.

Which is correct? What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: 'who' should have a preceding comma whereas that is fine without it.

Answer (score -1):

According to Advanced Grammar in Usa by M. Hewings, both are correct, but we use 'who' to refer to people, 'that' to refer to things. In addition, usa a comma before who.

Comment: Then that source is clearly wrong. “That” can also be used for persons

Comment: I won't be too formal for you. Look you say something you don't even know, I'm a student learning english and I'm certain that if you look for 'the best advanced grammar book' you will find out Martin Hewings' book. In addition, we don't say persons, say people in place of persons, use persons when you're using legalistic contexts.